# Always add parameter to command

Tags: bash

I have a command which always requires the same parameter to be input, is there anyway to automate this with bash?

I've tried something like the following, but this results in it then calling itself and getting stuck in a loop:

```
command-to-run() {
    command-to-run -parameter value
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `command` to bypass functions when doing name lookup:

```
command-to-run () {
    command command-to-run -parameter value "$@"
}
```

You also need to explicitly pass any arguments to your function to the "real" invocation using `"$@"`.

This is also a use case where an alias *is* still considered acceptable:

```
alias command-to-run="command-to-run -parameter value"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use alias

```
petr@ubuntu:~/dev/xmlparse$ ls
data.xml  test.py

petr@ubuntu:~/dev/xmlparse$ alias ls='ls -l'

petr@ubuntu:~/dev/xmlparse$ ls
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 petr petr 2021 Apr 24 10:38 data.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 petr petr  211 Apr 24 14:43 test.py
```